# My camera lens won't stay attached

Tags: lens, nikon

My camera fell while on the tripod and the lens fell off completely while the camera body remained on the tripod so when I reattached the lens it wouldn't stay it works and everything but I just have to hold it together. Should I try to take it to a camera shop  or just send the lens back to Nikon so I can get a new one ?

Comment: Send both the lens and body to Nikon. Or if you have a favorite local shop do that. It really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a problem with the lens, but it is more likely that the lens mount on the body has been damaged. You need to have either a local camera shop or a Nikon service center look at both the lens and the camera body.

Some things that will affect your decision:

- What body and what lens are we discussing? If it is an older entry level body and a relatively inexpensive lens, the repair by Nikon may actually cost more than the camera or lens is worth.
- Is your equipment still under warranty? Even if under warranty, Nikon may or may not cover damage from a fall on a tripod.

If you know anyone else with some Nikon gear, try using a different lens and another camera body with your camera and lens to see which component is the source of the problem.

Comment: I'm more inclined to think that the lens mount has actually become detached; either both parts of the bayonet are on the lens (likely, since it's just a few small screws anchored in plastic holding the lens mount in place on "consumer" bodies) or on the camera body (somewhat less likely, but still possible on some lenses). I can't think of a way in which a failure of thee lens release button would cause the lens to rotate through the 60 degrees or so required to detach the lens on a regular basis.

Comment: That's a possibility as well. I was thinking more in terms of a kit lens like the 18-55mm. If the lens release button isn't holding it the lens could be rotating when user17470 tries to zoom in that direction. Would AF work if the motor was in the lens? What about in the body? Is there no electronic communication between a non-motor body and an AF lens? Either way user17470 needs to have the camera/lens evaluated by a good repair shop and decide if the camera and/or lens is worth what the repair expense will be.

Comment: The electrical contacts are not part of the bayonet *per se*—the bayonet is not even used for electric bonding (grounding) on low-end models—so even if the mount had been ripped from the body, AF (and aperture) would work if the lens were manually held in place, yes (both in-lens and in-body AF).

Comment: I've seen a lot of plastic bayonet-mount tabs break off. If I had to guess, I would bet that is what happened.